NeatBeans 21 can't open projects in Maven and Ant
I downloaded NetBeans 21, but found it can't open project in Ants and Maven. When creating projects, there is no "projects name" shows in window as you can see the picture.

In the meantime, in Gradle it can open projects. I created a class in Gradle it can run. I use JDK 21. Is there anybody know how to solve this problem?
